# Entity Framework is Inserting entity when defining a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship using two existing entities in Entity Framework (v6.0) between **Countries** and **Regions** (a country may belong to many regions and a region contains many countries). Instead of simply adding the **CountryID** and **RegionID** to the join table however it's attempting to add a new **Country** record to **countries** table, resulting, of course, in a Conflict Error on the Primary Key as it attempts to add the **Country** to the table even though it's already there. ... here's the code ...

SQL Server Table definitions ...

```
CREATE TABLE [contact].[countries]
(
    [country_id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [country_name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    [country_code] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [country_capital] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [contact].[regions]
(
    [region_id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [region_name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    [region_desc] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [region_category] NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [created_by]         NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [created_date]       DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [updated_by]         NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [updated_date]       DATETIME NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [contact].[country_regions]
(
    [country_id] BIGINT NOT NULL , 
    [region_id] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([region_id], [country_id]),
    [created_by]         NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [created_date]       DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [updated_by]         NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [updated_date]       DATETIME NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CountryRegions_ToCountries] FOREIGN KEY ([country_id]) REFERENCES [contact].[countries]([country_id]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CountryRegions_ToRegion] FOREIGN KEY ([region_id]) REFERENCES [contact].[regions]([region_id]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Here are the model definitions ...

```
public class Country : BaseTimestampableModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Code { get; set; }

    public String Capital { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
}

public class Region : BaseTimestampableModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public String Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

The Code-First mapping code ...

```
    internal static void Map(ref DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entityMap = modelBuilder.Entity<Country>();
        entityMap.ToTable("countries", schemaName: "contact");

        #region map columns

        entityMap
            .HasKey(e => e.ID)
            .Property(e => e.ID)
            .HasColumnName("country_id")
            .HasColumnType("bigint")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired();

        entityMap
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasColumnName("country_name")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsRequired();

        entityMap
            .Property(e => e.Code)
            .HasColumnName("country_code")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsOptional();

        entityMap
            .Property(e => e.Capital)
            .HasColumnName("country_capital")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsOptional();

        #endregion map columns

        #region navigation props

        entityMap
            .HasMany(e => e.States)
            .WithOptional(s=>s.Country);

        #endregion navigation props

        TimestampableModelMapper.Map<Country>(ref modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class RegionMapper
{
    internal static void Map(ref DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entityMap = modelBuilder.Entity<Region>();
        entityMap.ToTable("regions", schemaName: "contact");

        #region map columns

        entityMap
            .HasKey(e => e.ID)
            .Property(e => e.ID)
            .HasColumnName("region_id")
            .HasColumnType("bigint")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired();

        entityMap
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasColumnName("region_name")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsRequired();

        entityMap
            .Property(e => e.Description)
            .HasColumnName("region_desc")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .IsMaxLength()
            .IsOptional();

        entityMap
            .Property(e => e.Category)
            .HasColumnName("region_category")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsOptional();

        #endregion map columns

        #region navigation props

        entityMap
            .HasMany(r => r.Countries)
            .WithMany(c => c.Regions)
            .Map(cr =>
            {
                cr.MapLeftKey("country_id");
                cr.MapRightKey("region_id");
                cr.ToTable("country_regions", schemaName: "contact");
            });

        entityMap
            .HasMany(r => r.States)
            .WithMany(s => s.Regions)
            .Map(sr =>
            {
                sr.MapLeftKey("state_id");
                sr.MapRightKey("region_id");
                sr.ToTable("state_regions", schemaName:"contact");
            });


        #endregion navigation props

        TimestampableModelMapper.Map<Region>(ref modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And finally the code which throws the error ... I use the same context to retrieve references to the **Country** and **Region** records so there should not be a cross-context issue, also I retrieve them using ID's, rather than passing in models to avoid issues of attaching and detaching entities; the retrieved instances are already tracked by the context.

```
Region region   = DbContext.Regions.Where(e => e.ID == regionID).SingleOrDefault();
Country country = DbContext.Countries.Where(e => e.ID == countryID).SingleOrDefault();

region.Countries.Add(country);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This all culiminates in the error ...

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CountryRegions_ToCountries". 
The conflict occurred in database "DataBaseName", table "contact.countries", column 'country_id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Of course I am not trying to INSERT a record into the "Countries" table, but all the mapping appears to be correct so I am not clear why it's trying to do this.

I have seen this problem posted several times but many are unanswered and the answers that are posted (that I have seen) have not worked for me. Most of the problems posted have been resolved by attaching the model back to the context ... this should not be a problem for me, however, since I am using a single context and working with already attached/tracked entities.

Any thoughts ... ?? Thank you for your help ...

Some of the suggestions I have tried ...

```
// 
// set the state to unchanged ...
Region region   = DbContext.Regions.Where(e => e.ID == regionID).SingleOrDefault();
Country country = DbContext.Countries.Where(e => e.ID == countryID).SingleOrDefault();

uow.DbContext.Entry<Country>(country).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
region.Countries.Add(country);
DbContext.SaveChanges();

//
// Add region to the country rather than country to the region
Region region   = DbContext.Regions.Where(e => e.ID == regionID).SingleOrDefault();
Country country = DbContext.Countries.Where(e => e.ID == countryID).SingleOrDefault();

country.Regions.Add(region);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem ... despite numerous examples to the contrary ... I mapped the many-to-many relationships in the RegionMapper backwards.

This is what it was ...

```
    #region navigation props

    entityMap
        .HasMany(r => r.Countries)
        .WithMany(c => c.Regions)
        .Map(cr =>
        {
            cr.MapLeftKey("country_id");
            cr.MapRightKey("region_id");
            cr.ToTable("country_regions", schemaName: "contact");
        });

    entityMap
        .HasMany(r => r.States)
        .WithMany(s => s.Regions)
        .Map(sr =>
        {
            sr.MapLeftKey("state_id");
            sr.MapRightKey("region_id");
            sr.ToTable("state_regions", schemaName:"contact");
        });


    #endregion navigation props
```

Simply switching the left and right keys made it work ...

```
        #region navigation props

        entityMap
            .HasMany(r => r.Countries)
            .WithMany(c => c.Regions)
            .Map(cr =>
            {
                cr.MapLeftKey("region_id");
                cr.MapRightKey("country_id");
                cr.ToTable("country_regions", schemaName: "contact");
            });

        entityMap
            .HasMany(r => r.States)
            .WithMany(s => s.Regions)
            .Map(sr =>
            {
                sr.MapLeftKey("region_id");
                sr.MapRightKey("state_id");
                sr.ToTable("state_regions", schemaName:"contact");
            });


        #endregion navigation props
```

I didn't read it all in detail but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192679/many-to-many-relationship-left-and-right-keys-flipped-after-entity-framework-5-u) suggests that perhaps the order was changed in EF5, which would make sense since most of the examples I was originally looking at were from EF4 implementations.